# Why are both exterior and interior walls constructed of concrete block in my home?

Tags: concrete

I bought this house 9 years ago, it was built in 1954. A few years after I had gotten it, I decided to get creative and pull down some of the paneling on a wall that separates the kitchen from the living room -to put a window-opening between the two rooms. That wall is all brick. Upon further inspection in all of the other rooms walls, I have discovered that every wall inside this house is constructed of brick. A few years ago the house next door to mine had a fire and when I saw the interior, I could tell that it was studs and drywall or paneling dividing he rooms, (the two houses were built around the same time and looked relatively similar, so I figure that they might have been built by the same builder), and I'm not complaining, having a nice sturdy structure, I am just wondering what compels some builders to use bricks for every single wall of a house when they construct it? I mean it, even the walls of the (tiny) closets are brick.

Comment: The Hydrogen Bomb/Joe McCarthy/Russians are coming?

Comment: Must have been built by the third little pig.

Comment: Perhaps the original house burned down and the owner didn't want to go through that again, so used masonry as much as possible. Or maybe the builder was a masonry contractor and didn't know any good carpenters. North America has relatively large timber resources so wood is usually the material of choice for home building, but people living in countries where wood is scarce think Americans are daft for building with wood due to fire potential.

Answer (score 2):

My house was also built around this time, and I have concrete walls under the tiny bed of sheetrock and paint. Back then materials as such were not as expensive and there was more of the material source, thus they used those source materials. As the country grew in numbers (people) certain materials became expensive and may have taken too long to set, so they went with the cheap route of using wood, thus making building a house much faster as well with putting little to no heart in the work. I'm proud to have a house built by a Masonry and for me I find it much safer, having a fireplace and all that could start a house fire if not properly cleaned/maintained. The above statements are merely more of an observation/my thoughts. Here is a link that might interest you. [Why Concrete?](http://www.doityourself.com/stry/building-houses-with-concrete-block--pros-and-cons#b)

Comment: I agree with your idea that back in the 50's, before conservation was taken seriously, lumber was probably used extensively and cement block was an upgrade. I can see why it would cost more: much more labor involved compared to wood framing. I would guess there might be less skilled masons (at the time) . I don't believe your answer should have been down voted. The person responsible didn't completely read  or understand your answer. I up voted.